# Jekyll website with Staticrypt protected post, Where to put the encrypted.html?

Tags: html, post, passwords, jekyll, protected

I'm using Jekyll for my blog. I want to protect some blog post with a password and I've decided to use Staticrypt.

I can encrypt the `index.html`page of one of my blog post with the Staticryp CLI and my custom `password_template.html`. It outputs a `index_encrypted.html`.

My question is: Where do I put the `index_encrypted.html`? I can't add it to the `_site` since Jekyll return the build to default everytime I serve it.

I tried adding the `index_encrypted.html` to the `_includes` folder and calling the page from the `.md` post like this:

`{% include index_encrypted.html %}` but this just break the page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

Here's what I did:

1. Put the `index_encrypted.html` in `_includes` and `_layouts`
2. Add a `permalink: /index_encrypted.html` in front matter of the `.md` post you're targetting.
3. Add a `layout: index_encrypted` in front matter of the `.md` post you're targetting.
4. Delete the whole markdown content of the `.md` post.
5. Voila!

You front matter should look like this:

```
---
title: 
date: 
tags: 
description: 
layout: index_encrypted
permalink: "/index_encrypted.html"
---
```

Edit: Make sure to create a copy of your `.md` post for later use.